# SSH tunneling with JDBC on Mac OS X - Problems

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ssh

I am currently developing a java application that uses JDBC inorder to connect to MySQL on a computer running Mac OS 10.6.7. The server that I connect to suddenly decided to use SSH. I've managed to connect to the database using MySQLWorkbench so there is nothing wrong with the connection.

My next attempt was to start the terminal and type ssh username@sshserver.com -L 3305:databaseserver:3306 and then start Eclipse and run my application. The terminal prompted me for my password but JDBC could not connect. I tried SSH Tunnel Manager with the following settings: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/146/sshb.jpg/ and it also prompts me for the password and then gives a green light. Still no success. The application worked fine before when i just connected without SSH. I would be very grateful for any help, I googled and tested every suggestion I found but nothing worked.

Comment: Try `ssh -fN -L 3306:databaseserver:3306 username@sshserver.com`

Comment: brilliant @trashgod! I was missing the -fN command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues to keep in mind using tunnels:

1. Remember that when you use a tunnel, your JDBC client should connect to localhost port 3305 (or 3306, whatever you're actually using). It shouldn't continue trying to connect directly to the remote host.
2. SSH will tunnel the connection to the remote end and try to connect to "databaseserver" port 3306 from there. If ssh on the remote host can't resolve the hostname that you gave it, it won't be able to make the connection. Since you are tunneling to the database server, you could try connecting to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem. A bit embarrassing of me to miss that. The only thing that is strange now is that when I use the terminal command that trashgod mentioned above, I get this output from the terminal every once in a while: "Read from remote host sshhost.com: Connection reset by peer". This happens even if I don't do anything.